# Не работает register_next_step_handler в telebot

Tags: python, telebot

bot.register_next_step_handler(send, request_city)
пропускается и программа сразу выводит Print ("check").
Не могу понять, тк предыдущая функция примерно такая же и всё исполняет.
В чём моя ошибка, кто-нибудь подскажет?

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from requests import request
import telebot

from config_parsing import new_request_command, edit_request_command, CATEGORY
from database import create_db, get_db_value
from exceptions import GET_API_ERROR
from config_parsing import new_request_command, edit_request_command
#from database import create_db

def get_commands(get_api: str):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(get_api)
    requests(bot, commands=new_request_command)
    

def get_telegam_api() -> str:
    dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
    if os.path.exists(dotenv_path):
        load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
        telegram_bot_api = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_BOT_API")
        return telegram_bot_api
    else:
        raise GET_API_ERROR


bot = telebot.TeleBot(get_telegam_api())


def requests(bot, commands):
    if commands == new_request_command:
        @bot.message_handler(commands=[commands])
        def new_request(message):
            send = bot.reply_to(message, "1-ый текст")
            chat_id = message.chat.id
            request_id = create_db(chat_id)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(send, request_category, request_id)
    elif commands == edit_request_command:
        pass
        #TODO добавить edit commands



def request_category(message, request_id):
    try:
        row_request = "request"
        request = message.text
        get_db_value(row_request,request, request_id)
        send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """2-ой текст""")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, request_city) #Эта часть не срабатывает
        print("check")
        
    except:
        category_error = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте написать название ещё раз""")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(category_error, request_category)


def request_city(message):
    print("check2")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """3ий текст""")

bot.infinity_polling()

if __name__=="__main__":
    get_commands(get_api=get_telegam_api())
```

Comment: Я могу заблуждаться, но мне кажется тут декораторов не хватает.

Comment: Как по вашему должна работать bot.register_next_step_handler?

Comment: Должен ждать ввод текста в телеграмме, и потом выполнять указанную там функцию. Сейчас она без ошибок сразу пропускается, не ожидая ввода и выполняет следующую команду

Comment: Нет, она ничего не ждет и не должна. Она просто регистрирует хендлер который сработает при получении данных от юзера. Она его зарегистрировала и пошла дальше